# How to switch back on integrated graphics on vga swicheroo Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, vgaswitcheroo

Everytime when I try to write `sudo echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` I get permission denied, I tried to run it as root, still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because redirection (`> /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`) is done by the shell, ***before*** running `sudo`.

```
echo DIS | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

will do what you want.